# Display random number as percentage

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm studying C# and I want to display the % sign after the random number showed in one label.
My code works well, but show only the number. I want the number with the percent sign:

```
Random randnum = new Random();
label_showRandNum.Text = randnum.Next(-1, 101).ToString();
```

I just don't know how to show the number with the percent sign (%).
I've tried to format the label, but without success. I also have a message to be shown when the number chosen is, for example, 10:

```
int number;
number = Convert.ToInt32(label_showRandNum.Text);
if (number == 10)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have picked 10%!");
}
```

I think the percent sign will cause an exception when converting the variable.
I do not know what to do. I will apreciate any help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx). You want the [P](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#PFormatString) specifier.

Comment: What kind of application you are targeting ? ASP.Net, WinForm , WPF ???

Comment: @Habib I'm working with a Windows Form Application, and this function is in the click event of one button.

Comment: When using P specifier the number is going to be multiplicated by 100.. you could concatenate the "%" character to the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options.

First use Format `p` or `P` in `ToString` like:

```
Random randnum = new Random();
label_showRandNum.Text = randnum.Next(-1, 101).ToString("p");
```

**But, the problem** with this is that, format `p` results in number multiplied by `100` and then a percentage sign is put next to it.

[Standard Numeric Format: "p" or "P"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Number multiplied by 100 and displayed with a percent symbol.

You can use `Random.NextDouble` method which produces values between 0 to 1, and then use that in your Label.

But the other option is:

You can **concatenate the `%` Percentage sign with your label**, and when you are parsing it you can remove it like:

```
label_showRandNum.Text = randnum.Next(-1, 101).ToString()
    + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PercentSymbol;
```

This will result in `Text` holding value like `10%`, For `en-US` culture.

Later when you are parsing the `Text` value to `int` you can do:

```
int number = int.Parse(label_showRandNum.Text.Replace
                         (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PercentSymbol,
                         ""));
```

I would rather use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PercentSymbol` then hard coding `%` symbol. As this might differ depending on the culture.

Comment: Thank you Habib. I did this with the second option, using the System.Globalization namespace.
More one step closer toward knowledge.
Once again, thanks all who also tried to help! A hug!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this??

```
 int number;
    number = Convert.ToInt32(label_showRandNum.Text);
    if (number == 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have picked "+number +"%!");
    }
```

Comment: [MSDN string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx) here is some further reading for Hypister +1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

To get a random number as a string with a `%` sign:

```
    Random randnum = new Random();
    string text = randnum.NextDouble().ToString("P0");   // note P0 will give you 
                                                         // zero decimal places
    Console.WriteLine(text);
```

To convert that to an `int` (or a `double`), you can do something like this:

```
    int value = int.Parse(text.Replace("%",""));
    Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Note that using the `P` format specifier will automatically multiple the number by `100`, which is why I used `NextDouble` to produce a number between `0..1` to give an output between `0..100%`. So if you want the original value back after parsing it, you'll need to divide it by 100 again.